# Amazon Firehose to transform the data from Kinesis and post it custom end point

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to see the transform the data from Kinesis to stream to my own system using a rest end point. I can do this using a lambda. I am wondering will using Amazon firehouse can help here? I am not able to figure out whether firehouse can write to third party rest services.

Answer (score 0):

The only service Kinesis Firehose can write to is Splunk. If you want Lambda to be triggered the destination would need to be S3 which would then trigger the Lambda.

Alternatively use Kinesis Data Stream which can have a Lambda function act as the consumer to push to your content to the third party. This would require transformation in the Lambda function.

*Additional Links*

- https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-firehose/
- https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-streams/